# Why do I'm getting these results from my regex matcher?

Tags: java, regex

I have this code below:

```
    String content = "title = 123";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(title)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

    int i = 1;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("groupCount() = " + m.groupCount());
        System.out.println("i = " + i++ + "     found: " + m.group(0));
        System.out.println("i = " + i++ + "     found: " + m.group(1));
    }
```

**The output is:**

```
groupCount() = 1
i = 1   found: title
i = 2   found: title
```

Can someone please tell me why I have 1 group count and also if I get correct values in `group(0)` and `group(1)`?

Are there any differences between `group(0)` and `group(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seed in the documentation:
[groupCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount())

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.

and
[group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

So group `0` is the whole string that will be matched.  and you have a capturing group with the whole string . So there is technically `2` group.

`0` is the default
`1` is your defined

Defined group indexing start from `1`.

Comment: So group 0 is like irrelevant for me?

Comment: yes sort of . you just need to use group `1` as counting start form `1`. and `0`  is default the whole match.

Comment: In that case, I will always have plus 1 more group?

Comment: yes you will have always plus 1 more group . but this `0`(default group) is not included in the `groupCount()`

Answer (score 1):

## Why I have 1 group count?

See [`Matcher` specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> `groupCount()`  - Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.

You only have 1 capturing group: `(title)`.

## Are there any differences between group(0) and group(1) ?

`group(0)` is the whole match (i.e. the string that was matched with the whole pattern), `group(1)` is only the substring captured with the first numbered capturing group. In your particular case, `group(0)` and `group(1)` are equal, because you set a capturing group to the whole pattern. Thus, the whole match (in `group(0)`) and the captured substring (in `group(1)`) coincide.

**Best practice** is not use a capturing group around the whole pattern since you always have access to it using `group(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

`group 0` is the entire string which is being used. Since you are *capturing* everything, `group 0` and `group 1` (which represents the first captured / matched group) will be same. If you had something like this :

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(title) = 123");` then you will be able to find the difference between groups 0 and 1.

Note : `group()` is same as `group(0)`